# WCF using REST, having some binding questions

Tags: wcf, wcfserviceclient

I am really confused right now and I can't get any right answers anywhere.

My confusions are:

1) Isn't wsHttpBinging (which is beefed up basicHttpBinding) used in SOAP instead of REST and REST only uses webHttpBinding?

2) Also, DOES silverlight 4 with WCF (REST) support wsHttpBinding (VS2010)? I read that it does not everywhere on the net but I some how got silverlight 4 working with REST using wsHttpBinding. 
NOTE: I am using Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory". Is this factory setting somehow bypassing my web.config setting for wsHttpBinding to make it work with webHttpBinding and i am thinking by my wsHttpBinding is working?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF uses SOAP by default - all binding except the webHttpBinding use SOAP.

If you want to do REST, you need to use the `webHttpBinding`.

> 1) Isn't wsHttpBinging (which is
>   beefed up basicHttpBinding) used in
>   SOAP instead of REST and REST only
>   uses webHttpBinding?

Yes - `wsHttpBinding` is a SOAP-based protocol - `webHttpBinding` is REST

> 2) Also, DOES silverlight 4 with WCF
>   (REST) support wsHttpBinding (VS2010)?

Silverlight 4 supports `basicHttpBinding` (SOAP), `netTcpBinding` (new in SL4 - SOAP) and `webHttpBinding` (REST).

> NOTE: I am using
>   Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory".
>   Is this factory setting somehow
>   bypassing my web.config setting for
>   wsHttpBinding to make it work with
>   webHttpBinding and i am thinking by my
>   wsHttpBinding is working?

Yes, if you use the `WebServiceHostFactory` in your SVC file, then you're really getting the `webHttpBinding` (REST) implicitly. The WCF runtime will *not* look at your web.config for infos - it has all the information and settings it needs when you use WebServiceHostFactory - and you get `webHttpBinding`.